# How smooth does reheating (after inflation) need to be?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, cosmic-microwave-background

Let's estimate the size of perturbations in the very early (GUT scale or earlier) universe required for consistency with CMB.

The CMB fractional temperature (and hence density) perturbations are of order $10^{-5}$. Those whose wavelengths are above the Jeans length had been growing, and in a radiation-dominated universe they grew as
$$
\delta \propto a^2
$$
For example, take GUT energy of order $10^{16}$ GeV, and $T \propto 1/a$, then the change in scale factor from GUT to CMB is about $10^{25}$. So this suggests the fractional perturbations after the end of inflation (assuming this energy scale) were no bigger than $10^{-55}$. That is a tiny number but I suppose that is one of the aspects of fine-tuning.

My question is, is that estimate right, and if so, then is there reason for confidence that the reheating process after the end of inflation will be sufficiently smooth and regular not to overwhelm these tiny perturbations? After all, the reheating is taking place in many regions which can no longer talk to one another since they are separated by more than the Hubble distance. So they cannot arrive at smoothness by that route. They just have to be going along independently but with this startling degree of agreement. Is that right?